# Error: [$sce:insecurl]

Tags: angularjs, controller, servicenow

I'm creating a Map widget in ServiceNow and am running into an Error: [$sce:insecurl].

My HTML:

```
<div class="fluidMedia">
<iframe ng-src="{{data.src}}" class="media"></iframe>
</div>
```

Server Script:

```
var gr = new GlideRecord('cmn_location');
gr.addQuery('sys_id', gs.getUser().getLocation());
gr.query();
if(gr.next())
{
var loc = gr.street.getHTMLValue();
}

loc1 = loc.replace(/,/g, "");
loc2 = loc1.replace(/ /g, "+");

data.src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyCmoLpiJFrdXLLUYsM3PRfPD0zQ0uATAUw&q=" + loc2;
```

Client Controller:

```
function($scope,$sce) {
    var c= this;
        c.server.get({name: "test"}).then(function(r) {
            c.data.src = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(r.data.src);
        });
 }
```

Has anyone encountered this?  How do I change the angular js to accommodate for this?  Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm brand new to angular js.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this url to the [whitelist of urls](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#resourceUrlPatternItem) via [`$sceDelegateProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider). Also read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl) for more details.